# Make a window appear on top of another, block access to other windows until button clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, always-on-top

Python 2.7, PyQt4.8.5

I want to have a main app window and then a second pop up window to display com port settings. This window should always be on top of the parent window until either the ok or the cancel button is clicked; closing the child window. (sort of like a required answer i.e. cant process until you choose the settings from the child window)

Is there a Python Qt command to do this?

Apologies if this has been asked/answered before, my search returned nothing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [modal](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs) dialog. For example:

```
dialog = QInputDialog()
dialog.exec_()
```

You can either implement your own dialog widget (by subclassing `QDialog`) or use one of the several available.