# Block QMainWindow while child widget is alive , pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I want when the user press the button a form will appear after MainWindow is blocked pending form filling

Comment: what do you mean with "how to block" in your question title?

Comment: MainWindow make inaccessible when the form appears

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) and show it using [exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec), which will block the rest of the application until it is closed. The return value of `exec` also tells you whether the form was closed without committing changes (i.e. cancelled).

Here is a simple demo script that shows how to use a `QDialog`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.checkbox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Option one')
        self.checkbox2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Option two')
        self.buttonOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Ok')
        self.buttonOk.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')
        self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.checkbox1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.checkbox2, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonOk, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonCancel, 2, 1)

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Dialog')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def handleButton(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted:
            print('Option one:', dialog.checkbox1.isChecked())
            print('Option two:', dialog.checkbox2.isChecked())
        else:
            print('Cancelled')
        dialog.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to do anything that the other answers suggest. Using any `exec()` methods is a surefire way to have bugs, since suddenly your gui code can be reentered. Don't do it.

All you need to do is to set proper window modality *before you show it* (that's the important part). So:

```
widget.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
widget.show()
```

If you wish the window to block only some other window, not the entire application:

```
widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | Qt.Window)
widget.setParent(otherWindow)
widget.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
widget.show()
```

Note that this code is for PyQt4 only, it won't work with Qt 5 as there, the window functionality belongs in a class separate from QWidget.

Comment: @Vesanto Exactly the same code works for me on PyQt5. Also (not to you) to read more about why not to use `exec` see Qt docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec, an example bug from there is `deleting the dialog's parent while the dialog is open via exec()`

Comment: how to show a dialog blocks only some windows rather than the entire application? I tried your code `widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | Qt.Window)
widget.setParent(otherWindow)
widget.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
widget.show()` but it does work?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
```

Comment: You are missing the "blocked pending form filling" part. The behavior asked is the one of exec_() for a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your QDialog or your QWidget with your form, and then connect it like this in the constructory of your main window.  You will want to convert this code from c++ to python:

```
QObject::connect(myPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(on_myPushButton()));

//...

void MainWindow::on_myPushButton()
{
    Dialog d;
    int retVal = d.exec();// this is a blocking call
    // Here the user has finished filling out the form.
    // save any data that should be in the form, or respond to the retVal

}
```

EDIT: Added link to docs on using `QDialog::exec()`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to put a widget(child window) not QInputDialog :/

Comment: To get blocking functionality you should use a `QDialog`.  It is a subclass of `QWidget` and can be used just like a `QWidget` in almost every way.  `QInputDialog` and `QMessageBox` and their static methods are useful subclasses of `QDialog`, but are not the only ones.

Comment: The `exec()` call creates an event loop and lets the GUI of the widget run in that loop, keeping it responsive.  You can see in the source, that it creates an event loop and runs it `exec()` and waits on that one.  https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/6382a038d6394135a4dc2d8e1e47133d9ea0b659:src/gui/dialogs/qdialog.cpp#L549

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so you want to block the parent window until the child window has been closed.

```
dialog = QInputDialog()
dialog.exec_()
```

Use the exec_() function , it will block until the child window is not closed

for further info :

[launch a PyQT window from a main PyQt window, and get the user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046882/launch-a-pyqt-window-from-a-main-pyqt-window-and-get-the-user-input)

[Python - make a window appear on top of another, block access to other windows until button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622090/python-make-a-window-appear-on-top-of-another-block-access-to-other-windows-u)

Comment: thnx, but I want to put a widget(child window) not QInputDialog

Answer (score 0):

must create Widget inherits from Qdialog

```
AjoutArBase, AjoutArForm = uic.loadUiType('ajoutArticle.ui')
class AjoutArticle(AjoutArBase,QtGui.QDialog):
```