# show Qwidget window without MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget

I am having problems showing a QWidget window for the user to input some data.

My script has not GUI, but I just want to show this small QWidget window.

I created the window with QtDesigner, and now I am trying to show the QWidget window like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from input_data_window import Ui_Form

class childInputData(QtGui.QWidget ):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(childInputData, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFocus(True)
        self.show()
```

And then, from my main class, I am doing like that:

```
class myMainClass():

    childWindow = childInputData()
```

That gave me the error:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

So now I am doing, from my main class:

```
class myMainClass():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    childWindow = childInputData()
```

Now there is no error, but the window is showed twice and the script does not wait until the data is entered, it just shows the window and continues without waiting.

What is wrong here?

Comment: About the window showing twice, I can't see why in the code you posted. Are you sure you don't call `show()` somewhere else in the code ?

Comment: yes I was :S .....my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly normal that the window is shown and the script goes on: you never told the script to wait for the user to answer. You just told it to show a window.

What you would like is the script to stop until the user is done and the window is closed.

Here's one way to do it:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class childInputData(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(childInputData, self).__init__()
        self.show()

class mainClass():

    def __init__(self):
        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win=childInputData()
        print("this will print even if the window is not closed")
        app.exec_()
        print("this will be print after the window is closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m=mainClass()
```

The `exec()` method "Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called" ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#exec)):
the script will be blocked on the line `app.exec_()` until the window is closed.

NB: using `sys.exit(app.exec_())` would cause the script to end when the window is closed.

---

An other way is to use `QDialog` instead of `QWidget`. You then replace `self.show()` by `self.exec()`, which will block the script

From the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details):

> int QDialog::exec()
>
> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it

---

Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414435/4720935) of a related question advocates not to use `exec`, but to set the window modality with `win.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)`. However this doesn't work here: it blocks inputs in other windows, but do not block the script.

Comment: thanks that was exactly the behaviour I was looking for

Comment: no. both pages will open on qwidget case. maybe you're right on qdialog case

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the `myMainClass`...do something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from input_data_window import Ui_Form

class childInputData(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(childInputData, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Ui_Form()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.setFocus(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 win = childInputData()
 win.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks jramm, I know I can do that, I have been actually doing my GUIs like that,  but in my questoin I meant that I would like to show the widget window from inside my class, that is not possible?

Comment: I dont see why it wouldn't work if you move the `win.show()` to the `__init__` method of the class...but what difference does it make?

Comment: thanks again, no difference, just wanted to learn if that was possible