# Python crashes when trying to switch qt screens in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

as stated in my about me i am currently working on a interface for a database for swimming pool "De Leewal" in Exloo, The Netherlands

Well, I am trying to make the person able to switch screens (With a button, Like "Back to the main menu")

But when i hooked up the code and pressed the button, i get a screen saying: Python crashed (In dutch)
...
Does anyone spot the mistake?

Here is my code:

MainWindow.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import ButtonFunctions

global mariadb_connection
global cursor
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='root', database='leewaldb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(407, 394)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("media/Icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(9, 41, 4, 255), stop:0.085 rgba(2, 79, 0, 255), stop:0.19 rgba(50, 147, 22, 255), stop:0.275 rgba(236, 191, 49, 255), stop:0.39 rgba(243, 61, 34, 255), stop:0.555 rgba(135, 81, 60, 255), stop:0.667 rgba(121, 75, 255, 255), stop:0.825 rgba(164, 255, 244, 255), stop:0.885 rgba(104, 222, 71, 255), stop:1 rgba(93, 128, 0, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.CopyRightLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CopyRightLabel.setObjectName("CopyRightLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.CopyRightLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ExitButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ExitButton.setObjectName("ExitButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ExitButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ShowEverythingButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShowEverythingButton.setObjectName("ShowEverythingButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ShowEverythingButton, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.DeletePersonButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.DeletePersonButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.DeletePersonButton.setObjectName("DeletePersonButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.DeletePersonButton, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.WelcomeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.WelcomeLabel.setObjectName("WelcomeLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.WelcomeLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.AddPersonButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.AddPersonButton.setObjectName("AddPersonButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.AddPersonButton, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.SearchSpecificButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SearchSpecificButton.setObjectName("SearchSpecificButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SearchSpecificButton, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "BezoekersDatabase Leewal Hoofdmenu"))
        self.CopyRightLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "© N.S. Geldorp & H. Nahumury 2017"))
        self.ExitButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.ShowEverythingButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Iedereen geregistreerd in deze database"))
        self.DeletePersonButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Verwijder iemand uit de database"))
        self.WelcomeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welkom bij de bezoekersdatabase voor het zwembad \"De Leewal\" te Exloo"))
        self.AddPersonButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Voeg iemand toe aan de database"))
        self.SearchSpecificButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zoek een specifiek persoon"))
        self.ExitButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.MainWindow.ButtonExitPressed)
        self.ShowEverythingButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.MainWindow.ButtonShowEverythingPressed)
        self.DeletePersonButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.MainWindow.ButtonDeletePersonPressed)
        self.AddPersonButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.MainWindow.ButtonAddPersonPressed)
        self.SearchSpecificButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.MainWindow.ButtonSearchSpecificPressed)

def mainforbuttonfunctions():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TheMainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ButtonFunctions.py:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import MainWindow as TheMainWindow
import sys

global mariadb_connection
global cursor
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='root', database='leewaldb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

class MainWindow():
    def ButtonExitPressed():
        cursor.execute("shutdown")
        exit()

    def ButtonShowEverythingPressed():
        pass

    def ButtonDeletePersonPressed():
        pass

    def ButtonAddPersonPressed():
        pass

    def ButtonSearchSpecificPressed():
        pass

class ShowEveryone():
    def ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed():
        self.close
        TheMainWindow.mainforbuttonfunctions()
```

ShowEveryone.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ShowEveryone.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import ButtonFunctions
import MainWindow as TheMainWindow

class Ui_ShowEveryoneInDatabase(object):
    def setupUi(self, ShowEveryoneInDatabase):
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.setObjectName("ShowEveryoneInDatabase")
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.resize(409, 396)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("media/Icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.setWindowIcon(icon)
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(9, 41, 4, 255), stop:0.085 rgba(2, 79, 0, 255), stop:0.19 rgba(50, 147, 22, 255), stop:0.275 rgba(236, 191, 49, 255), stop:0.39 rgba(243, 61, 34, 255), stop:0.555 rgba(135, 81, 60, 255), stop:0.667 rgba(121, 75, 255, 255), stop:0.825 rgba(164, 255, 244, 255), stop:0.885 rgba(104, 222, 71, 255), stop:1 rgba(93, 128, 0, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ShowEveryoneInDatabase)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.LijstWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.LijstWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.LijstWidget.setObjectName("LijstWidget")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LijstWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.setObjectName("ReturnToMainMenuButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ReturnToMainMenuButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel.setObjectName("IedereenInDatabaseLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(ShowEveryoneInDatabase)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ShowEveryoneInDatabase)

    def retranslateUi(self, ShowEveryoneInDatabase):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ShowEveryoneInDatabase.setWindowTitle(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "ToonIedereen - Leewal Database"))
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.setText(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "Terug naar het hoofdmenu"))
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel.setText(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "Iedereen in de database:"))
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.clicked.connect(ButtonFunctions.ShowEveryone.ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_ShowEveryoneInDatabase()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advance.

-Natan

P.S. If you leave an downvote, please leave an reason and be prepared to remove it if i fix it or prove that it was unfair to leave it.

Comment: It actually crashes. Which platform are you on? This is generated code is it not?

Comment: You have multiple files calling app.exec_(). This is the Qt event loop and should be called only once. Also you login to the database through a static variable which doesn't seem right. What is the entry point?  What function is called first when you start your program?

Comment: @PaulRooney I am on windows and it is generated using QtDesigner and the ui/py converter inserted in the pyqt module.

Comment: @DavidChing This is the correct way, this is the way that is stated in the MariaDB Documentation.

Comment: Are you executing main() from `ShowEveryone.py` or `MainWindow.py`?

Comment: @DavidChing I am executing main from ShowEveryone.py.

Comment: @DavidChing We still here?

Comment: @DavidChing hello?

Comment: @DavidChing I am on a time-base here!!! not trying to be inpolite but i am on a schedule and i need your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very confusing.  Below is `ShowEveryone.py` rewritten.  It is the only file you need for this example (it looks like the others were previous attempts of experimentation).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ShowEveryone.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import ButtonFunctions
import MainWindow as TheMainWindow

class ShowEveryone(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ShowEveryone, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self.setupConnections()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("ShowEveryoneInDatabase")
        self.resize(409, 396)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("media/Icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(9, 41, 4, 255), stop:0.085 rgba(2, 79, 0, 255), stop:0.19 rgba(50, 147, 22, 255), stop:0.275 rgba(236, 191, 49, 255), stop:0.39 rgba(243, 61, 34, 255), stop:0.555 rgba(135, 81, 60, 255), stop:0.667 rgba(121, 75, 255, 255), stop:0.825 rgba(164, 255, 244, 255), stop:0.885 rgba(104, 222, 71, 255), stop:1 rgba(93, 128, 0, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.LijstWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.LijstWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.LijstWidget.setObjectName("LijstWidget")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LijstWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.setObjectName("ReturnToMainMenuButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ReturnToMainMenuButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel.setObjectName("IedereenInDatabaseLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "ToonIedereen - Leewal Database"))
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.setText(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "Terug naar het hoofdmenu"))
        self.IedereenInDatabaseLabel.setText(_translate("ShowEveryoneInDatabase", "Iedereen in de database:"))

    def setupConnections(self):
        self.ReturnToMainMenuButton.clicked.connect(self.ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed)

    def ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed(self):
        self.close()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ShowEveryone()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Other than the restructuring, the root cause of your crash is that your slot:

```
class ShowEveryone():
    def ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed():
        self.close
```

did not have an instance of the 'ShowEveryone' class.  Another issue is your member method `ButtonBackToMainMenuPressed` does not have a `self` parameter.  Finally you need to include parenthesis to call `self.close()`.

BTW, if Python crashes, please include the traceback, e.g.

```
python.exe ShowEveryone.py
  File "ShowEveryone.py", line 9
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Great! thank you! There was no traceback, there was just this windows screen thing popping up saying "Python has crashed." Kind of like, Good luck hope you fail.

Comment: Okay this is how i stop that screen but how do i open the MainWindow.py screen?

Comment: Glad it unstuck you!  I've seen that Windows screen thing when running the app from PyCharm on MacOS.  It's because you need to edit the PyCharm's BreakPoints "Any exception" to Suspend, so that the stacktrace is dumped.

Comment: I think you kind of need to restart from scratch because you have MainWindow and ShowEveryone but you said you started the app from ShowEveryone which means MainWindow doesn't exist.  If you started the app from MainWindow, and that somehow shows ShowEveryone as a popup, that would be different.  Then when you clicked Back, the ShowEveryone would close itself, and MainWindow would then be the active window in your app.  But your MainWindow.py is a mess, it doesn't open the ShowEveryone window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410663/block-qmainwindow-while-child-widget-is-alive-pyqt